# Sending input to embedded terminal in vim

Tags: python, vim, terminal-emulator

In my `.vimrc` file I have included the following line:

```
autocmd vimenter * botright term
```

This means that, whenever vim starts, it will open a terminal at the bottom-right.
I would like to create a key-mapping that makes vim run a given, dynamically-generated command at the terminal. For example, I have added the following to my `.vimrc` file:

```
nmap <leader><leader> <C-w><C-w>python my_python_file.py<CR><C-w><C-w>
```

So if I am editing a file called `my_py_file.py`, I can press `<leader><leader>` and vim will first change windows (changing to the embedded terminal), then enter the command

```
python my_python_file.py
```

so that the file will run in python, and finally change back to the other window so that I can continue editing. This works! But I would like it to work for arbitrary files, not just for files that are named `my_python_file.py`. How can this be accomplished?

I have thought about using `expand('%:p')` to get the full path of the current file, but I have not been able to pass this string to the embedded terminal window as input. I have tried writing a function to accomplish this, but with no success.

Comment: Did you look into `term_sendkeys()`? That might be able to achieve what you want. If you find a solution, post it as an answer, I'm also interested in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use `map <expr> <leader><leader> ...` so that `<leader><leader>` can be mapped to a dynamically-generated binding. The below code snippet from a `.vimrc` file works with Vim 8.0:

```
" open a terminal directly below current window
nnoremap <leader>t :split<cr><c-w><c-j>:terminal ++curwin<cr><c-w><c-k>
" save current file and run python on it in terminal window directly below
nnoremap <expr> <leader><leader> ':w<cr><c-w><c-j>python ' . expand('%:p') . '<cr><c-w><c-k>'
```

This maps `<leader>t` to open a new terminal buffer, and `<leader><leader>` to run python in that terminal buffer. Note that the terminal stays in Terminal-Job mode the whole time.

Slight modification will be needed for this to work with NeoVim:

```
" open a terminal directly below current window
nnoremap <leader>t :split<cr><c-w><c-j>:terminal<cr><c-w><c-k>
" save current file and run python on it in terminal window directly below
nnoremap <expr> <leader><leader> ':w<cr><c-w><c-j>ipython ' . expand('%:p') . '<cr><c-\><c-n><c-w><c-k>'
```

In the NeoVim version, we must change from Terminal-Normal mode to Terminal-Job mode before passing input to the terminal, and then return to Terminal-Normal mode.